# Is there any way to deploy NEXT.js app to a linux server without 'building' the app inside the server?

Tags: linux, next.js, deployment, digital-ocean

If i want to deploy a small to medium sized Next.js project to a small (512mb or 1gb ram) linux server - when i run

```
npm run build
```

often the server crashes and needs to be restarted.
i need an easy solution to this.

Tried building it locally and send .next folder to server and seemed it didn't work.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you'd like to build the application on one server and deploy it on another? Simply compress the generated contents and clone them onto the host machine, install dependencies and call `yarn start`. Of course this is just the theory.

Comment: i wanted to build locally and deploy that to a server.